# How to set entity to object?

Tags: java, jpa, swt

I have SWT button and in abstract class giving him Entity from JPA User with data.

```
public class ButtonEntities extends Button{

  private User user = null;

  protected void checkSubclass() {} 

  public ButtonEntities(Composite parent, Integer style)
  {
    super(parent,style);
  }

  public User getUser()
  {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(User user)
  {
    this.user = user;
  }
}
```

I want use universal button for all Entities what I have. can I do it somehow?
something like `setEntity(Entity) getEntity()`?

Comment: Could you show your abstract class where you are giving entity?

Comment: SWT is not happy to override his components

Comment: `setData(...)` and `getData(...)` is official way to hold some objects connected to SWT components